# How do I send the keys to view BluRay or DVD video on a computer other than the one with the DVD Player?

Tags: video, encryption, video-streaming, streaming

I have a need which is to read a movie from a DVD or BluRay player, send that movie data to another computer over an Ethernet network connection, then decode the MPEG-2 video for display on that other computer.

```
 +-----------+             +-------------+
 | DVD Drive |             | Video Board |
 +----+------+             +-------------+
      |                           ^
      v                           |
 +-----------+             +------+----+
 |           |             |           |
 | Computer  +------------>| Computer  |
 |    A      | Ethernet    |    B      |
 +-----------+             +-----------+
```

Now, most DVD/BluRay disks have a protection that prevents simple ripoff of disks, so I'm thinking that it may not be possible or not that easy to implement such.

Am I suppose to get a key from the DVD/BluRay disk and send that to the video card of computer B for decoding purposes? Or is playing the disk on computer A giving me already decrypted data that I can then forward to computer B?

Comment: See [Advanced Access Content System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Access_Content_System)

Comment: in fact  you could 'play' and encode the videostream again to send it further, however you are loosing some quality and you will need decent power to do so

Comment: @gusto2 So you think that the decryption includes decompression too? That would be annoying, but I thought the decompression would be the video card responsibility?